# segmentation fault while inserting node at specified position of singly linked list using c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, position, singly-linked-list

It works well when I insert node at 0th position,but not when I insert somewhere in the middle .I have kept pointer prev to traverse till the previous node of target position and i have also checked if the node is to be inserted at the tail position. I have no idea why it is giving segmentation fault .Can anyone help me out in solving this problem?
code is:

```
Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    Node * temp=new Node;
    int i=1;
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    Node * prev;
    if(position==0)
        {if(head==NULL)
        head=temp;
         else
             {

             temp->next=head;
             head=temp;
             }
        }

    else
    {
        prev=head;
        while(i!=position)
           {
           i++;
            prev=prev->next;
        }
        if(prev->next=NULL)
            {
            prev->next=temp;
        }
      else
            {
            temp->next=prev->next;
            prev->next=temp;

        }  
     }  
    return head;

}
```

Comment: If you want to insert an element not at index `0`, you have to generate a node to each index before that.

Answer (score 3):

Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) nobody can really help you. Nevertheless, this sticks out in a major way:

```
if(prev->next=NULL) {
    prev->next=temp;
}
```

You assign `NULL` to `prev->next` instead of comparing it with `==`.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt below code :

```
while(i!=position)
           {
           i++;
            prev=prev->next;
        }
```

You should modify condition like this

```
while(prev && i!=position)
{
  i++;
  prev=prev->next;
}
```